# How to fix Java Erorr Message

Tags: java

I installed Java on my pc but when I run any java program it says error.I tried the following code

```
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.print("This is just an example...");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same thing. Please edit your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have does not have any problem at all.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("This is just an example...");
    }
}
```

Possible error would be the FileName.java, make sure that it is `Main.java` because Classname must be identical to the File Name.